# Can't make Dell Gateway 5000 with Ubuntu Core 16 as Access Point.

Tags: network-manager, ubuntu-core

I am working on Dell Edge Gateway 5000 series and have installed Ubuntu Core 16. I am trying to make it as Access Point. I have inserted a sim card in it and have created a connection with the command below.

nmcli con add type gsm ifname ttyACM3 con-name  apn  user  password

When I run the command nmcli con, I am able to see that connection registered. But when I try to up that connection, I am getting the following error.

```
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.
```

Please let me know what steps to follow to connect to the sim card network.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are missing the "con-name", and activating the connection.

It should be something like

```
nmcli c add type gsm ifname <interface> con-name <name> apn <operator_apn>
```

Where:

- < interface > → ttyACM#
- < name >  → Connection's name assigned by you ('my-sim-connection' , 'sim-internet', etc.)
- < operator_apn > → ISP's APN (Internet Service Provider). You can find it on google.

> You can change the < interface > value with '*'. This means it's going to get the first compatible gsm interface.

Then you have to  activate the connection

```
nmcli r ppp0 on
```

Here depends on the interface you have. Somecases it could be ppp0, ppp1, wwan, wwan0.

Please read [this official article.](https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-cellular-connections)